# Magento - Product Alerts Without Registering

Tags: magento

Does anyone know if it is possible to allow users to sign up for product alerts without registering?  Ie. by just entering their email.

Doesn't seem like this is a default option.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As I am sure you have noticed this is not standard functionality. However, IMHO product alerts are not ideal anyway as there is no means of finding out what product alerts you have, i.e. a report.

If you only have a few product alerts then you may want to develop your own solution purely in template code, i.e. with a CAPTCHA and simple email submit box that talks to your own php script (to then email you the product + email). You can then correspond with the potential customer to offer them an alternate product, place a special order for them and so on.

From a programming perspective the above is a 'non-solution', however, from a customer service perspective you can do a lot better than the normal stock alerts.